# Get params by paramset?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, you can assign params to paramsets. You can check which paramset using `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName`. Is there anything more intelligent you can do? Easily get all the params in that paramset that were passed?

I want to require that one and only one param in a paramset was passed. Wondering if there's a more elegant, built-in solution than checking and counting $PSBoundParams against a static list of keys.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. PowerShell uses `ParameterSets` as a form of pseudo-overloading, for validating that allowable combinations of parameters are set. It is your responsibility as the coder to ensure that the parameters you need are filled out; some of this can be done with `[Parameter(...)]` decorations (e.g., `Mandatory`, `Validate...`), you have to actually check values and make sure that any particular values make sense for your application. See (among other references) [MSDN on PowerShell parameter validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714432(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$PSBoundParameters` to find the parameters that are user-populated.  It is a `[HashTable]` with a couple bonuses.

Ex.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param([Parameter(ParameterSetName='Custom1',Position=0)]
      [String]$ex)
$PSBoundParameters.Keys

PS C:\>ex.ps1 Example!
> ex
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Switch` on `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` to do things with the parameters.

```
Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
{
  '__AllParameterSets' { }
  'Custom1' { }
}
```